# The development server returned error code 500

Tags: react-native

I want to run react-navigation.
It gives me this error for gesture handler. While I'm going to install gesture handler, the following error occurs.
Kindly give me the appropriate solution.

```
C:\Users\Farooq\FirstActivity>npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Farooq\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-11T21_17_29_196Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please format the code and console output you post, this is barely readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical issue with windows environment.

- First of all download git for windows from [here](https://gitforwindows.org/)

**Then follow bellow steps**

1. Open Your Environment Variables
2. Edit **Path**
3. Find your git location that been installed in your device. Example is `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`
4. Add the git location to **Path** (make sure to add this to both **user variables** and **system variables**)
5. Apply the changes and restart your pc
6. Lastly, go back to your project and run `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`